# Object is not subscristable django

Tags: python, django, list

i have a function which is trying to get all the elements from a model and agroup them in a list, but when i try to get the query, i get the error `'Customer_Group' Object is not subscritable`..

I am using two methods `get_groups` is to obtain the list and `process_all_groups` is for create the list.

Where is my mistake in here?:

```
@api_view(['POST', 'PUT', 'GET'])
@permission_classes([LoginRequired])
@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])
def get_groups(request):
    resp = {'dat': '', 'message': 'no se encontro groups', 'success': False}
    database = request.user.company_select.company_db
    try:
        groups = Customer_Group.objects.using(database).all()
        if groups:
            list_groups = process_all_groups(groups, database)
            resp = {'dat': list_groups, 'message': 'exito!', 'success': True}
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        resp.update(dict(message='Error'))
    return Response(resp)

def process_all_groups(groups, database):
    list_groups = list()
    for group in groups:
        group['id_group'] = Customer_Group.objects.using(database).values().filter(id_group=group['id_group'])
        group['group_code'] = Customer_Group.objects.using(database).values().filter(group_code=group['group_code'])
        if group:
            list_groups.append(group)
    return list_groups
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Where does `group_aux` originate from? Please do not use a global object. It is an antipattern and likely is the cause of the problems here. If `group_aux` is a `Customer_Group`, then indeed you can not use `group_aux['id_group']`, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ok, i have done what you said, but still get the same error.. I edited the question code so you can see what i did, any sugestion?

Comment: `group` is ` a `Group` object, so `group['id_group']`  makes no sense. If you want to add a dictionary, you can use `{ 'id_group': ..., 'group_code': ...}`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i get the idea, but can you give me an example? i am new with python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what i wanted and solve my problem, i did this:

```
def process_all_groups(groups, database):
    list_groups = list()
    for group in groups:
        group = Customer_Group.objects.using(database).values().filter(id_group=group.id_group)
        if group:
            list_groups.append(group)
    return list_groups
```

I get the query with a filter(), and put the value in a variable to finally append in the list...